# keras.layers.TimeDistributed with Huggingface Transformer gives NotImplementedError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I wanted to apply Bert on a sequence of sentences in the following manner, but I am getting a NotImplementedError

How to reproduce :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(50, 64), dtype='int32')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(model)(inputs)

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-631f3cd2e8b2> in <module>
----> 1 outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(model)(inputs)
```

Whereas the code would work fine for

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: you have to wrap a single layer into TimeDistributed

Comment: @MarcoCerliani can you clarify what do you mean by wrap a single layer?

Comment: TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))(xxx) or TimeDistributed(Dense(...))(xxx) not TimeDistributed(model)(xxx)